# iOS Application Memory used

Tags: ios, objective-c, ram

I would like to know total RAM used by my application with code.

I have tried the following :

```
vm_statistics_data_t vmStats;
    mach_msg_type_number_t infoCount = HOST_VM_INFO_COUNT;
    kern_return_t kernReturn = host_statistics(mach_host_self(), HOST_VM_INFO, (host_info_t)&vmStats, &infoCount);
    if(kernReturn == KERN_SUCCESS) {
        printf("\nwire_count:%f",(vmStats.wire_count/1024.0));
        printf("\nactive_count:%f",(vmStats.active_count/1024.0));
        printf("\nfree_count:%f",(vmStats.free_count/1024.0));
        printf("\ninactive_count:%f",(vmStats.inactive_count/1024.0));
    }
```

It shows to me :

> wire_count:256.197266
>
> active_count:951.602539
>
> free_count:98.450195
>
> inactive_count:739.317383

But in the instruments, XCode shows me 9,2mb used by my application !!!

What's wrong here ?

Thanks

Comment: Should you be using task_info? Could be a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182924/where-is-my-ipad-runtime-memory-going)

Comment: I have tried it, it shows me 10.2mb, but in the other side, XCode is showing in instruments 12,1mb. Any Ideas ?